# MySQL UNION vs JOIN with OR in clause

Tags: mysql, join, union

I have one table `TableA` with columns `[AccountID, Email]`. I have another table `TableB` with `[AccountID_1, AccountID_2, email]`. I need to match the `AccountID` in `TableA` with either of the `AccountIDs` in `TableB`. Neither of these approaches seem to be working. The first one seems to be stalling or just taking forever (both tables have several hundred thousand entries). The second has the error `"Can't reopen table: TableB".`

## Attempting JOIN with OR

```
select count(distinct TableA.id) from TableA
    JOIN TableB ON TableB.AccountID = TableA.AccountID_1 
    OR TableB.AccountID = TableA.AccountID_2
;
```

## Attempting sql UNION

```
select count(distinct b.id) from (
    select * from TableA
    join TableB on TableB.AccountID = TableA.AccountID_1 
    union
    select * from TableA
    join TableB on TableB.AccountID = TableA.AccountID_2
) as b;
```

Comment: On the union attempt you are forgetting to say 'join TableB on TableB.AccountID...' the second time around which is why it's giving you an error.

Comment: Sorry that was just an error in putting my query into SO. I've corrected it.

Comment: Are there indexes on all 3 `AccountID`* columns? Have you run `explain` on the `join` query to see what indexes are or are not getting used?

Comment: Those two queries are going to potentially return two different results. What is it you need a count of? The number of rows from tableA that had a match? Or the number of rows from tableB?  We might guess that \`id\` is unique and non-NULL in tableA, but we are just guessing. Before we write SQL, we need to know what our result is supposed to be. We can write all sorts of queries that will "work" as far as returning a result. But without a specification, those queries could return anything, with no way to tell if what they return is right or not.

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
select count(*) from TableA where
exists ( select 1 from TableB where
AccountID in (AccountID_1,AccountID_2))
```

Answer (score 0):

For the first one, the column name being selected is wrong. The following seem to work fine.

**Attempting JOIN with OR :**

```
select count(distinct `TableA`.AccountID) from `TableA`
    JOIN TableB ON (TableA.AccountID = TableB.AccountID_1 
        OR TableA.AccountID = TableB.AccountID_2);
```

**Attempting SQL UNION**

```
select count(distinct b.AccountID) from (
    select `AccountID` from TableA
    join TableB on TableA.AccountID = TableB.AccountID_1 
    union
    select `AccountID` from TableA
    join TableB on TableA.AccountID = TableB.AccountID_2
) as b;
```